# Сайт в интернет

Tags: localhost, site

Есть сайт,есть Open Server,я смог сделать так что б мой сайт открывался у меня на компе,но мне нужно что бы и другие могли открывать мой сайт по ссылке. Как сделать??
Попробовал роутер настроить но ничего

Comment: Может быть есть смысл на хостинг залить?

Comment: @АлександрСемикашев Я бы хотел иметь локальный хостинг

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во первых название директории сайта должно совпадать с вашим локальным ip адресом. Во вторых должен быть проброшен порт 80 через роутер на ваш пк с сайтом. В 3-х у вас должен быть белый ip адрес. Если адрес серый то попробуй no-ip.com.

Comment: А как мне узнать белый IP или нет?

Comment: Позвони провайдеру интернета

Comment: А через комп нельзя узнать самому?

Comment: Ну ещё вариант поставить VPN но это должно быть у всех пользователей сайта.(я про серый ip)

Comment: Ну сначало пробрось порты потом если не конектится звони провайдеру.

Comment: Не забудь привязать по мак адресу ip пк сайта  что бы не менялся.

Comment: Если у вас ип начинается с 192.168 или 10. 0. То он серый. У провайдера можно подключить белый ип.